# Rolar o conteúdo da DIV sem que o conteúdo saia da DIV

Tags: css, css3, posicionamento

Olá, estou com um problema, gostaria que minha DIV do canto direito acompanhasse o conteúdo da esquerda até acabar o conteúdo da esquerda, só que se eu colocar position fixed na DIV da direita ela fica fixa até o final da página. imagens do problema.Alguém pode me ajudar? :(

```css
/* DIV COM AS DUAS COLUNA */
#paginas {
   max-width: 1024px;
   display:block;
   float:left;
}

/* DIV DA ESQUERDA COM CONTEÚDO DE ROLAGEM */
#paginas-coluna1 {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  max-width:520px;
}

/* DIV DA DIREITA QUE DEVERIA FICAR FIXA AO LADO DO CONTEÚDO DA ESQUERDA ATÉ ACABAR O CONTEÚDO DA DIV PAGINAS-COLUNA1*/
#paginas-coluna2 {
  display:block;
  float: right;
  max-width: 504px;
  height: 730px;
}



/*CONTEUDOS INTERNO DA DIV DA DIREITA */ 


#campo-video2 {
  display:block;
  float:right;
  height: 270px;
  width: 466px;
}
#carga-horaria {
  width:273px;
  height:106px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#2BABE1;
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 18px;
}
#botao-matriculapagina {
  width:194px;
  height:106px;
  display:block;
  float:right;
  background-color: #008DD1;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#botao-matriculapagina2 {
  width:91px;
  height:32px;
  line-height:32px;
  font-weight:normal;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#2BABE1;
  font-size:14px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

[image: Como era pra ficar]

[image: Como está ficando]

Comment: Gostei da imagem, é bem explicativa, porém não teria como você fazer um exemplo com uma pequena parte disto no code snippet(é um botão que adiciona código executável quando você está criando a pergunta bem parecido com o jsfiddle) ou entao no próprio http://jsfiddle.net :D

Comment: Paulo, obrigado pelo apoio, estou providenciando o código como solicitado :)

Comment: Pesquise no Google sobre Sticky Footer. Acho que isso resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Use os valores `table`+`table-cell` para a propriedade `display` do CSS:

```
.div-pai {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.div-filha-esquerda, .div-filha-direita {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Isso fará os conjuntos de divs se comportarem como tabela, alinhando suas alturas.

Obviamente, **não** funciona em IE < 8.
*Se* tiver que dar suporte para IE<8, use um [comentário condicional](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/condcom.php) para incluir o alinhamento por CSS ([aqui](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) e [aqui](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)), ou, em última tentativa, por JavaScript.

---

Se você quiser que somente parte do conteúdo seja esticado até o final, use `position:absolute` com `bottom: 0` e o `top: [xx]px`. Onde [xx] é o deslocamento fixo do topo. Se quiser algo mais dinâmico, terá que ser por JavaScript, acredito.

```
.conteudo-esticado {
  position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.div-esticado-esq, .div-esticado-dir {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```css
.paginas {
  display: table;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
}
.paginas-coluna1,
.paginas-coluna2 {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
.paginas-coluna1 { background: #ff9999; }
.paginas-coluna2 { background: #9999ff; }

.conteudo-espichado {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.div-espichada-esq, .div-espichada-dir {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.div-espichada-esq { background: #dd4444; }
.div-espichada-dir { background: #4444dd; }
```

```html
<div class="paginas">
  <div class="paginas-coluna1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla molestie turpis quis urna dapibus gravida. Maecenas ac mi id nibh volutpat ultrices. Duis vehicula nec urna ac volutpat. Nulla nec tortor sit amet diam iaculis euismod. In hac habitasse platea
    dictumst. Nulla facilisi. Quisque consequat quam id leo efficitur hendrerit. Pellentesque luctus mattis massa, quis dapibus erat ullamcorper ut. Nunc neque justo, consequat ac nunc nec, molestie dictum nisi. Pellentesque suscipit ac nunc id bibendum.
    Ut nec pharetra odio. Maecenas gravida erat vel condimentum tempus. Duis sit amet massa lobortis, pellentesque sapien et, feugiat mauris. Curabitur ac urna nec magna bibendum dapibus id sit amet ex. Sed et leo posuere, aliquam mi vel, auctor lorem.
    Cras blandit orci vel diam ullamcorper commodo.
  </div>
  <div class="paginas-coluna2">
    <div style="height:80px">imagem aqui por exemplo, ou uma div com altura fixa</div>
    <div class="conteudo-espichado">
      <div class="div-espichada-esq">conteudo</div>
      <div class="div-espichada-dir">conteudo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="paginas">
  <div class="paginas-coluna1">
  </div>
  <div class="paginas-coluna2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla molestie turpis quis urna dapibus gravida. Maecenas ac mi id nibh volutpat ultrices. Duis vehicula nec urna ac volutpat. Nulla nec tortor sit amet diam iaculis euismod. In hac habitasse platea
    dictumst. Nulla facilisi. Quisque consequat quam id leo efficitur hendrerit. Pellentesque luctus mattis massa, quis dapibus erat ullamcorper ut. Nunc neque justo, consequat ac nunc nec, molestie dictum nisi. Pellentesque suscipit ac nunc id bibendum.
    Ut nec pharetra odio. Maecenas gravida erat vel condimentum tempus. Duis sit amet massa lobortis, pellentesque sapien et, feugiat mauris. Curabitur ac urna nec magna bibendum dapibus id sit amet ex. Sed et leo posuere, aliquam mi vel, auctor lorem.
    Cras blandit orci vel diam ullamcorper commodo.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Andre, só que ainda não foi solucionado o principal problema que seria a coluna da direita descer até o fim do conteúdo da coluna da esquerda, exemplo nas imagens, tem como fazer algo com position fixed ? algo assim?

Comment: @LeonardoMax o que não funciona? vc não quer que a altura div da direita acompanhe a altura da div da esquerda?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.. dê uma olhada